# Javascript SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for integrate a post-it application in my django website with Javascript/JQuery.

I found something as a tutorial and I tried to insert it in my script but I get SyntaxError :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement      post-it.js:2:19
```

I don't know Javascript langage so it's a bit complicated for me, but I don't see where `;` is missing :/

This is my HTML post-it part :

```
<h1>Post-It</h1>
<input type="button" value="Ajouter un Post-It" id="btn-addNote" />
<div id="board"></div>
```

This is my Javascript file :

```
(function ($, $S) {
// $jQuery
// $S window.localStorage
// Déclaration des variables
var $board = $('#board'),
// Placement des Post-It
Postick, //Object Singleton contenant les fonctions pour travailler sur le LocalStorage
len = 0,
// Nombre d'objets dans le LocalStorage
currentNotes = »,
// Stockage du code HTML de l'élément Post-It
o; // Données actuelles du Post-It dans le localStorage

// Gérer les Post-It dans le LocalStorage
// Chaque objet est enregistré dans le localStorage comme un Object
Postick = {
add: function (obj) {
obj.id = $S.length;
$S.setItem(obj.id, JSON.stringify(obj));
},

retrive: function (id) {
return JSON.parse($S.getItem(id));
},

remove: function (id) {
$S.removeItem(id);
},

removeAll: function () {
$S.clear();
},

};

// S'il existe des Post-It on les créer
len = $S.length;
if (len) {
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
// Création de tous les Post-It se trouvant dans le localStorage
var key = $S.key(i);
o = Postick.retrive(key);
currentNotes += '<div class="postick"';
currentNotes += ' style="left:' + o.left;
currentNotes += 'px; top:' + o.top;
// L'attribut data-key permet de savoir quelle note on va supprimer dans le localStorage
currentNotes += 'px"><div class="toolbar"><span class="delete" data-key="' + key;
currentNotes += '">x</span></div><div contenteditable="true" class="editable">';
currentNotes += o.text;
currentNotes += '</div></div>';
}

// Ajoute tous les Post-It sur le tableau de bord
$board.html(currentNotes);
}

// Dès que le document est chargé, on rend tous les Post-It Draggable
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".postick").draggable({
cancel: '.editable',
"zIndex": 3000,
"stack" : '.postick'
});
});

// Suppression du Post-It
$('span.delete').live('click', function () {
if (confirm('Etes vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette note ?')) {
var $this = $(this);
// L'attribut data-key permet de savoir quelle note on va supprimer dans le localStorage
Postick.remove($this.attr('data-key'));
$this.closest('.postick').fadeOut('slow', function () {
$(this).remove();
});
}
});

// Création du Post-It
$('#btn-addNote').click(function () {
$board.append('<div class="postick" style="left:20px;top:70px"><div class="toolbar"><span class="delete" title="Fermer">x</span></div><div contenteditable class="editable"></div></div>');
$(".postick").draggable({
cancel: '.editable'
});
});

// Sauvegarde tous les Post-It lorsque l'utilisateur quitte la page
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
// Nettoyage du localStorage
Postick.removeAll();
// Puis on insère chaque Post-It dans le LocalStorage
// Sauvegarde la position du Post-It, afin de le replacer lorsque la page est chargée à nouveau
$('.postick').each(function () {
var $this = $(this);
Postick.add({
top: parseInt($this.position().top),
left: parseInt($this.position().left),
text: $this.children('.editable').text()
});
});
}
})(jQuery, window.localStorage);
```

Thank you :)

PS : I thing that the SyntaxError comes from there right : `currentNotes = »,`

Comment: -2 ? My question is focus on a real problem ...

Comment: quote your » with ' »'.

Comment: `currentNotes = »,` should be `currentNotes = '»',`

Comment: @Shree and @Mamun Thank you, but I still have my SyntaxError with `;`

Comment: `« »` are French quotation marks. If you use them in your French texts, I give you an award because you are among the very few people who respect typography. But in your code, French quotes must be considered as strings. In JavaScript, only English quotes (`' '` or `" "`) and `\`backticks\`` (ES6) are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Protip: When developing, keep indentations cool. You indentation here is a mess and is difficult to follow code blocks. I know you are new so don't worry, but just get used to have a clean indentation.

Now, if you get the code and run it, elsewhere (Chrome console, jsfiddle or whatever) it tells you the exact line where the error is happening, as is a SyntaxError and that kind of errors happens when the engine is checking the code, but not running it, so is not needed to have all the needed libs loaded along with the code.

If you check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8now04xs/1 In the console you will notice that the error comes from the line 54, and if you click on it (Being in CHrome DevTools) it will lead you directly to the line with the problem: [http://i.imgur.com/G8tPl92.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/G8tPl92.gifv)

You were right, the error code comes from the line you said. The problem is that is not a string, nor a number or a valid keyword. Is a non-valid character.

I don't read all the code, but I guess that you want it to be a string. In JavaScript (and almost all languages), strings must be quoted with either single or double quote, like this:

```
currentNotes = "»",
```

If you look around the rest of the code, you will se a lot of strings following this pattern, so you can understand better how this works. If you want it to be an empty string then you have to it right this:

```
currentNotes = "",
```

If you look closely, it makes sense.

After fixing this error, the fiddle will fail, as it will try to run the code and encounter a lot of problems because not running in your Django environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;) It's the first time I'm reading Javascript script. About indentions, all my scripts are well-indented.

I took this js script on a website because it's a post-it javascript demonstration. So exceptionnally I just copy/paste in my Django website.

In firebug, I have the line post-it.js:2:19 so it means line 2 element 19 or line 19 element 2 ?

Comment: @Deadpool Line 2, character 19. The problem is that Django sandboxes your script in some way, so is not the real line you have in front of you. That's why I said to run it elsewhere. For example, check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8now04xs/1/ If you look at the console it says line 54, and in Chrome DevTools if you click on it it will lead you to the exact line (see gif): http://i.imgur.com/G8tPl92.gifv (I love Chrome DevTools xD)

Answer (score 0):

I check your code on [jshint](http://jshint.com/).
There is 2 problem.

1 . Quote `'»'` [I already mention about this on comment.]

2. Missing `;`

```
   }; // Missing ; in this line.
})(jQuery, window.localStorage);
```